# AWS Cognito get user location

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

we are developing some POC. We have a case use case like when the users sign in with username and password, we get access, id and refresh token. But we need the access, id and refresh token to include users location. I tried using pre token generation trigger. But am not able to get the location information about the user. Please help to guide.

Comment: What do you mean by "location"? Are you referring to a field that is already associated with the user in some system?

Comment: I mean when the jwt is generated by the aws cognito. I want to add the location attribute to the jwt being generated using pre-token trigger. But I am not sure where the user location attribute will be available in the trigger to be added inside the jwt.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein